# Problem using org.apache.commons.net.telnet.* with android

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem using the `org.apache.commons.net.telnet.*` library in my Android application and I was hoping someone could help me.

I have implemented an app which uses telnet to communicate with a remote server and all works fine.  The problem I have is when I call `TelnetClient.disconnect()` the method does not return. When calling the method when running a test case (meaning sans Android, just through Eclipse) it returns immediately, but on Android something is screwing it up. My test case looked something like:

```
TelnetClient telnet = new TelnetClient();
telnet.connect(ipAddress, port); 
telnet.disconnect(); //HERE
```

Could anyone enlighten me as to why this may be?

If I obtain an `InputStream` from the connected telnet object and some info is sent from the telnet server after disconnect has been called, it can cause the method to return and closes the comm thread which was created by calling `.connect(..)`, which makes me think there is some sort or lock being held somewhere?

What would the fundamental difference be between the Dalvik VM or Android OS and my Java VM and XP machine to cause the behavior?

Thanks for any help, stack traces below!

I have a stack trace from the comm thread created by the `TelnetClient.connect()` at the time the ANR appears (as a result of the disconnect call indefinitely hanging).

```
"Thread-15" daemon prio=6 tid=17 NATIVE | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N                obj=0x43812d90 self=0x1be528 | sysTid=1403 nice=-2 sched=0/0 handle=2703408 
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.receiveStreamImpl(Native Method) 
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.receiveStream(OSNetworkSystem.java:236) 
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:550) 
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:87) 
  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:67) 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:177) 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:259) 
  at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:160) 
  at org.apache.commons.net.io.FromNetASCIIInputStream._read(FromNetASCIIInputStream.java:77) 
  at org.apache.commons.net.io.FromNetASCIIInputStream.read(FromNetASCIIInputStream.java:175) 
  at org.apache.commons.net.io.FromNetASCIIInputStream.read(FromNetASCIIInputStream.java:138) 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:177) 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:259) 
  at org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetInputStream._read(TelnetInputStream.java:122) 
  at org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetInputStream.run(TelnetInputStream.java:564) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
```

And also from the thread calling `.disconnect()` (which for my test case is just on the main thread):

```
DALVIK THREADS: "main" prio=5 tid=3 MONITOR | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N   obj=0x4001ab08 self=0xbc60 | sysTid=1390 nice=0 sched=0/0 handle=-1343996920 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:~166) 
  at org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetInputStream.close(TelnetInputStream.java:535) 
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:81) 
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(BufferedInputStream.java:167) 
  at couk.mypackage.comm.TelnetClient.closeTelnet(IGSTelnetClient.java:441) 
  at couk.myoackage.comm.Translator$1.handleMessage(IGSTranslator.java:65) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

#### Update:

If I close the output and input streams explicitly (which the javadoc says NOT to do), but to call `disconnect()` instead, then I can close the connection, i.e.,

```
out.close();
in.close();
telnet.disconnect();
```

I'm confused!

Comment: Can you clarify the difference between "test case" and "on Android"? Is it the `AndroidTestCase` you're running on an emulator/device, or completely separate JUnit?  Does the problem occur on the emulator, or device, or both?

Comment: Sorry, i should be clearer.

By test case i just mean running the code on my laptop (not on any android emulator / device just through eclipse). 'on android' means using the emulator on the same machine. Havent tested on a device (as i dont have one as yet!) so can only speak for the emulator (running 1.6). 

Hope this clarifies the above

Comment: No problem, you can also edit your original question to help clarify for others. :)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have you considered using SSH instead of Telnet? Telnet is very insecure (not encrypted) and has been replaced by SSH on most platforms. There are client libraries available, too.

Comment: The server i am communicating with uses telnet, so SSH not an option, no need for secruity here though!

Comment: Question: is this comm thread still trying to read from the input stream while you try to disconnnect?  Also, can you open an adb shell and run the versions that hangs.  While it is hung, run netstat at the shell prompt and see what status it gives for the connection.

Comment: did you checked http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/ src code? I think they had telnet.

Comment: I'm watching this one, I wanted to make my own Foobar Remote Control app and while the http server one works well, I miss the telnet one. I've got the experience to do it now, so I'll keep an eye on this, and upvoted it.

Comment: Unable to reproduce - do you have any sample code?

Comment: Why can't I see the `disconnect()` method anywhere on the second stack trace? Is it done in different thread? Also, have you eliminated that this could be because other threads are using the `TelnetClient`?

Answer (score 1):

`TelentClient extends Telnet` and `Telnet extends SocketClient`. If you see these classes, it will create `VT100` connection. See the below code from `TelnetClient.java`.

```
 public TelnetClient() {
   /* TERMINAL-TYPE option (start)*/
   super ("VT100");
   /* TERMINAL-TYPE option (end)*/
   __input = null;
   __output = null;
 }
```

This will now create the super classes. See the code from `Telnet.java` class.

```
Telnet() {
      setDefaultPort(DEFAULT_PORT);
      _doResponse = new int[TelnetOption.MAX_OPTION_VALUE + 1];
      _willResponse = new int[TelnetOption.MAX_OPTION_VALUE + 1];
      _options = new int[TelnetOption.MAX_OPTION_VALUE + 1];
      optionHandlers = new TelnetOptionHandler[TelnetOption.MAX_OPTION_VALUE + 1];
}
```

The `DEFAULT_PORT` here is `23`.

Now, see the `connect` method from `SocketClient.java`.

```
        public void connect(InetAddress host, int port)
                throws SocketException, IOException {
            _socket_ = _socketFactory_.createSocket(host, port);
            _connectAction_();
        }
```

This is creating a new `Socket` using `DefaultSocketFactory`, which is a TCP socket to specified Host and Port. In the `connectAction` method, its setting the timeout for the new socket.

Now, when we call `disconnect`, its first trying to close the socket.

```
public void disconnect() throws IOException {
            _socket_.close();
            _input_.close();
            _output_.close();
            _socket_ = null;
            _input_ = null;
            _output_ = null;
            _isConnected_ = false;
        }
```

Because you are able to close the Streams directly, so seems the problem with the socket itself.

This will be a TCP socket, and i don't know how Android behaves with TCP. Can you please check on that? Because this method is doing closing of 3 private members. OR may be the socket is already closed so that it can't close it again?

Hope this helps.

Thanks.